# What does "they" in "they're not" refer to?

Tags: meaning

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Oracle says to Neo about hacking programs:

> Oracle: The ones doing their job, doing what they were meant to do,
> are invisible. You'd never even know they were here. But the other
> ones....Well, you hear about  them all the time.
>
> Neo: I've never heard of them.
>
> Oracle: Of course you have. Every time you've heard someone say they
> saw a ghost or an angel... ...every story you've ever heard about
> vampires, werewolves or aliens...is the system assimilating some
> program...that's doing something **they**'re not supposed to be doing.
>
> Neo: Programs hacking programs.

What does "they" in "they're not" refer to?

Comment: The antecedent is "some program," and Oracle is using "they" as a gender-neutral third-person singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this labeling scheme help?

> Oracle: The ones[A] doing their job, doing what they[A] were meant to do, are invisible. You'd never even know they[A] were here. But the other ones[B]....Well, you hear about them[B] all the time.
> Neo: I've never heard of them[B].
> Oracle: Of course you have. Every time you've heard someone[C] say they[C] saw a ghost or an angel... ...every story you've ever heard about vampires, werewolves or aliens...is the system assimilating some program[D]...that's[D] doing something they're[D] not supposed to be doing.

Also, in terms of the overall meaning, the [D]s are the same entities as the [B]s from earlier in the conversation.